# Insert a shadow on a header image

Tags: css

I would like to put a shadow on the header image but it didn't work.

URL: http://testjeanschwartz.weebly.com/

I already try something like this:

```
.wsite-background
{
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

Putting a shadow is something I already did a lot of times but this one is not working.

Thanks.

Comment: strange because here it works as expected

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: Internet Explorer & Google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `box-shadow` is covered by the elements that follow it (namely `#main-wrap`). You can change the `z-index` of your element to have it show 'above' other elements.

You will need to `position` your element something other than `static` for the `z-index` to be acknowledged:

```
.wsite-background {
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 5px #888888;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: You don't need z-index here. Just position: relative will do

Answer (score 0):

For background image, you need `inset` property to handle it with the position relative or absolute.

Try this one:

```
.wsite-background{
   position:relative;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 5px #888888;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 5px #888888;
   box-shadow: inset 0px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```